# How to tell when there is a connection database issue?

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, logging

I need to make a special treatment when a connection problem to the database is occurring like database server down and not an sql problem.

In the source code we can get various exceptions but which ones are belonging to the connection ones ?

We would like if this kind of problem occurs to make less logs.

**EDITED**

I have many methods that perform connection to the database but all get the session from the same method (initSession):
Here an example:

```
private Session initSession(HibernateUtil hibernateUtil) {
        Session oSession = null;
        try {
            oSession = hibernateUtil.getSession();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("unable to log, Please check the details of your database");
        }
        return oSession;
}


public List findAlerts(int pFirstLine, int pNbElement) throws AnalyzerException {

        List oAlerts = new ArrayList();
        Session oSession = initSession(lHibernateUtil);
        try {
            oAlerts = AlertFinders.instance().findAlertByStatus(oSession, false, pFirstLine, pNbElement);
            Iterator iterAlerts = oAlerts.iterator();
            while (iterAlerts.hasNext()) {

                ...
            }
        } catch (UnableToLocateObjectException eU) {
            throw new AnalyzerException(eU.getMessageSource(), eU.getClassNameSource(), eU.getMethodSource(), eU);
        } finally {
            oSession.close();
        }
        return oAlerts;
}
```

Comment: Please find the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple possible ways.

- Use Java Connection [isValid](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid%28int%29) method.
- Use connection pool - All major connection
  pools support this functionality (including c3p0 and dbcp).They can
  throw SQLException has getErrorCode() and getSQLState() methods
- Write Java code & poll frequently - sample code below

*Run arguments sample: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE system mypassword123 oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver*

```
    public class DbConnCheck {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            String url = args[0];
            String username = args[1];
            String password = args[2];
            String driver = args[3];

            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            try {
                Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL");
                while(rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getObject(1));
                }
            } finally {
                conn.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit : Adding details on hibernate part
Not done in Hibernate but to be precise you can check in connection pool configuration.

If using c3p0 then check how you can best use setting like idle_test_period, preferredTestQuery and testConnectionOnCheckout; 
If using dbcp then validationQuery can do the job.

If you want to use c3p0 with Hibernate and Spring check [this](http://www.jvmhost.com/articles/hibernate-famous-communications-link-failure-last-packet-sent-successfuly-issue-solved-c3p0) link

Comment: just a question: at what stage we can detect a problem accessing the database? when getting a session from the SessionFactory, when getting a Connection object..

Comment: We already use c3p0 and idle_test_period is set to 5 seconds and testConnectionOnCheckout seems to be working only  with hibernate 2.x.
 ___ Assuming this scenario: we have X pooled connections, and my application was going on. but suddenly the database crushed. what will happen ?
___ Every 5 seconds a test will be performed but that does it mean that all the X connections will be removed ?
and if the database still not recovered, my application will try to create new connections which will throw exceptions ?